# gmaps-samples call to OpenGL ES API with no current context

Tags: android, api, google-maps

i'm trying to develop a app with Google Maps API v3 in Android.
The code is reference by this site https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/android_v3#nextsteps
(the codes detail is regular , so i do not post again !)

But, when i launch my app, logcat feedback the messages for me

```
11-22 14:40:22.530: E/libEGL(24624): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
```

How can i solve with this problem ?